# How to connect to Cosmos DB using Proxy IP using Python

Tags: python, authentication, proxy, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect to Cosmos DB using python using below proxy host and port. The Cosmos DB is configured to accept ip = 100.100.10.0/25

But, it seems to not connect.

Exception says- `azure.cosmos.exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError: (Forbidden) Request originated from client IP 198.110.10.10 through public internet. This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings.`

Python Code:

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient, exceptions, ProxyConfiguration

url = 'XXXX'
key = 'XXXX'

d = ProxyConfiguration()
d.Host = '100.100.10.0'
d.Port = 25
client = CosmosClient(url, credential=key, proxy_config=d)

database_name = 'testDatabase'
try:
    database = client.create_database(database_name)
except exceptions.CosmosResourceExistsError:
    database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
```

Exception:

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\azure\cosmos\_synchronized_request.py", line 158, in _Request
raise exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError(message=data, response=response)
    azure.cosmos.exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError: (Forbidden) Request originated from client IP 198.110.10.10 through public internet. This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but your need add your Proxy Host to firewall in Cosmos DB.

[image]

BTW, firewall changes may take up to 15 minutes.

Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-firewall